# Home page manageable content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP website which has a home with a top banner and 2 more controllable panel like [here](http://secondopinionbooks.com/home.png).

My question is what is the best way to keep this controllable via admin?

The way I did it was to create two categories by the names "Latest Updates" and "New in 2013!" and then coded it such that the posts coming under the categories gets displayed in their respective panels on the home page. The image as usual controlled via the Featured Image of the post. A pretty basic setup to manage its content via posts to keep the layout intact and at the same time do the task.

I had suggestions where we should keep it right there in WP editor for control i.e. put all the div / ul / li etc. right there in the WP editor using the text part and have the admin control it right from there.

I need to know which method is better for implementation i.e. managing via posts like it is now or keep it right there in the editor and put HTML content in the editor.

All recommendations much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first one method is correct ,easy and safe.

Safe Because,If accidentally any change in editor then all showing content breaked